# Eclipse Egit - is it possible to compare commits on different projects?

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, egit

At the new workplace where I work, in the past, the main project was split in two **`branches`**, because different customers began to have very different requirements. A pretty common scenario I guess.

Now, I'am not a developer but a sysadmin, and not an expert of **`git`**, but I was wondering if in these cases usually is the correct approach to use **`branches`**, because in my understanding a **`fork`** would be more adapt.

What the CTO is asking me to do, is to migrate this branch, **into a new git repository**. But he also says that he wants to still be able to perform comparisons between commits, therefore (in eclipse + egit) to `right-click on workspace > team > show in history > select the commits he wants to compare > click on compare to each other`. I believe that these requirements conflict to each other, so my main question is: is it possible to compare commits of different git repositories?

My second question is, if a project with the same core that starts to require different features, should be branched forked or moved to a new repository?

Hope my question is not too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept called *fork* in Git. Git hosting services, such as Github or Gitlab, provide such a feature. As far as Git is concerned, a fork is essentially just a branch. And also, every clone of a repository - even local repositories - are essentially forks.

To split up your repository into two repositories that have a *fork* relationship, first just create a clone of the repository. And then delete branches in both repositories that refer to commits of the now-other-repository.

The usual approach to compare forks is to add a remote to the other remote. This is possible in your case too, since you have common commits in both repositories, before the *forking-point*. More on remotes here: [What is "git remote add ..." and "git push origin master"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617211/what-is-git-remote-add-and-git-push-origin-master)

Comment: 1.Thank you for your precious answer, I believe that by saying "are essentially forks" in the last part of first paragraph you meant "are essentially branches" : ) 

2.Could you please explain better: add a remote to the other remote? should I add a remote on each repository, each one pointing to the other repo? the remote should be of push type, or fetch type? I think fetch type, but just to be sure

Comment: @lese You're right indeed, what I meant to say is that there is little difference between the terms fork and branch, as far as Git is concerned. You got that right, let's say you're on `old_repo` and want to compare/view commits of `fork_repo`, so you add a remote to `fork_repo`. As long as you only need read access on the `fork_repo`, a fetch type remote would be fine.