# From git clone to git pull

Tags: git, push, clone, pull

I am still new to git and vs code, I wanted to pull a repository from GitHub to use it in my vscode. I used the clone option in vs code instead of pulling. Now every edit I make and every commit is done only on my local machine. Now I need to sync what I did with other team members and I don't know how to do that??

Comment: [This article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) might have what you are looking for.

Comment: open cmd in windows or terminal in Linux , then write `git clone your repo address` and then open vs code and open that project you cloned . see [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

Comment: It is also worth checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617211/what-is-git-remote-add-and-git-push-origin-master).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the github viscose extension and it's really useful and so simple

Answer (score -1):

I strongly advise you to use the github vscode extension if you are not familiar with git cli, otherwise every changes should be staged:
git add .
Then committed:
git commit -m "my commit"
Finally pushed:
git push  origin  main
Main is the branch name  you must watch some YouTube tutorials about git and github i recommend you Traversy Media git & github crash course