# Push changes simultaneously to github and gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci

I am new to using gitlab. I have imported a repository from github to gitlab. When I push new changes to my repository, the changes are reflected in github. How do I update these changes to gitlab as well?

Comment: Add GitLab repository as a new remote, then push to it as well. It may benefit you to read [What is "git remote add ..." and "git push origin master"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617211/what-is-git-remote-add-and-git-push-origin-master), and [Working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) chapter of Git Book.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+two+repositories