# I get the "fatal: unable to access 'repository': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push some modifications into a git repository, but get the message: "I get the `fatal: unable to access 'repository': The requested URL returned error: 403`

Allow me to give you a few more details:

1. I work on Linux Ubuntu, 20.04.3 LTS
2. I use my PAT which I recently generated as a password.  (I am pretty sure it is fine, because it doesn't give me the `Authentication failed` error.
3. In my `.bashrc` file, I have the following lines:

```
git config --global user.name  "Niceno"
git config --global user.email "bojan.niceno.scientist@gmail.com"
```

which are both correct, and have been working for several years now.

4. The `.git/config` reads:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/DelNov/T-Flows
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "development_branch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/development_branch
```

which doesn't tell me much.
5. If I log in in the Git account `DelNov`, to which I have admin rights, I see that the user `Niceno`, my humble me, is granted access to repository.

I am really baffled, because I am trying to do something which I was doing for years.  Yet all of a sudden, I can't do a simple push.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't push, but can you do other actions such as pull?

Comment: Just a quick reminder, before making a push you should make an update and a commit. Also another reason why such issues can occur is that your git project might have a previous Github repository and you have in that case to override those previous credentials. It may also be a temporary issues, and in that case you may just retry later.

Comment: @SOROMEED: Yes, I can perform pull.  It tells me all is up to date because I cloned just just a few minutes ago, changed one file and tried if I can do the push.

Comment: @HimmelsDJ: I did the commit and, as I wrote to SOROMEED, I did the clone just a few minutes ago.

Comment: Are you 100% positive that you have the right to push on that repo and/or branch?

Comment: Ok if so then it's likely a git origin issue, I mean the push you make is likely forwarding to another repository.

Comment: @SOROMEED: I just double checked, I am among the users who can contribute to that repository.  I am trying to attach a screenshot, but seem to be unable to in this comment.

Comment: I tried to do the same from another computer in a different network, and faced the same issue.  @HimmelsDJ: how do I check if pushes go to a different repository?

Comment: Apparently just anyone can *read* `https://github.com/DelNov/T-Flows` (I just did, in a browser). Your 403-forbidden suggests that your credential helper is supplying the wrong user name and/or PAT. Note that 403 *is* "authentication failed", in this case.

Comment: @torek: I am pretty sure I have write access.  If I open a file from the repository in a browser, logged in as myself, I can edit files directly.  I am really clueless, it never happened to me and I am regularly using git for several years now.  Did something change recently on Github, like in the last couple of months?

Comment: They went to PAT-only: if they think what you're sending them is a password, they reject it. How they decide some string is a PAT and not a password, I don't know (perhaps some sort of checksum or type signature at the front?). (For my own part, I always use ssh instead of https to write to GitHub.)

Answer (score 1):

I read your explanation and I hope this is what to did:

1. git add.
2. git commit -m "My first commit"
3. git push https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git --all

From the comments I understand that this is the first push of this project to the repository. So in this case it's advisable to set the **full url https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git --all** instead of just doing *git push origin --all*.

I understand the fact that you were used to the git command lines but just in case you forgot some things [this link will strongly help you as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617211/what-is-git-remote-add-and-git-push-origin-master)

**UPDATE:**

I cloned and push the project base on the github url you provided in the comment. After doing this:

> $ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/new_repo

Make sure you've clicked on the "copy" icon that is at right end of the repository's url from you github account to grab your real this ( **git@github.com:username/new_repo** ) without blank spaces added. Doing that I received a notification as the folder is empty ( Not a problem). Then I did:

> $ git push -u origin master

And there came a fatal error, a rejection for push. But to force push I did:

> $ git push -f origin

This gave a clue of the rejection it was about, then to force push the project and bypass the rejection I did this with my github account opened on browser on the same system:

> $ git push --set-upstream origin main

And the push was successful. About the process to add an existing project to a new github repository take a look at this [link](https://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html)

and take a look at the part that says "**A new repo from an existing project**" to make sure you started well. But if you do :

> $ git push --set-upstream origin main

you should be able to get rid of the 403 rejection. But you might be connected to your github account on the system you're pushing with.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but also without success.  I get the same error as before: 
remote: Permission to DelNov/T-Flows.git denied to Niceno.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/DelNov/T-Flows.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

In the meanwhile I also removed user Niceno from DelNov/T-Flows and invited him back as a contributor.  It was to no avail.

Comment: I cloned and pushed successfully the project from the url you gave. Take a look at the update I made in answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.  In the meanwhile I seem to have found a different workaround.  I created a new PAT with all check boxes which appear on the page for updating PAT checked.  That also resolved the issue.

Comment: Ok, great then !

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local repository folder and find a hidden folder called ".git". find a file called "config" in the folder as attached below.
[image]

You need to change the url = https://github.com/... to SSH url that can find from GitHub repository(on git hub Web portal) cone menu as below picture.

[image]

This is what the config file looks like, after the change of the url.
[image]

This solved my issue. I believe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

"I am trying to push some modifications into a git repository, but get the message: "I get the fatal: unable to access 'repository': The requested URL returned error: 403"

This has just happened to me too but upon checking properly **I have realized that my token has no permission to push to my repo**, if you are facing this issue **check your token permission or delete your token and generate a new one with all access grant**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).